# detailed instructions on how to change the dns of the Ethernet i am using

Tags: raspbian, dns, lxterminal

I am very new to raspberry and I am trying to change the dns of the ethernet to get around dns blocks. I have tried the codes listed in other answers for a question like this but I must be doing something wrong because it never works. Please make the answer as detailed as possible because I have no clue what I am doing.

Comment: You need to include ALOT more info... for starters are you using Jessie or Wheezy?  and what have you tried that is not working, be specific, link specifically to the instructions that are not working out for you.  Otherwise all anyone can do is start asking 20 questions, which is not productive at all.

Answer (score 1):

open terminal  (press `Ctrl+Alt+T' in gnome)

Enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then enter:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Press `Ctrl+X` and type `y` to save

Then enter:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

That will add google as a dns entry. You can also use your router (typically 192.168.1.1 or type `ifconfig` in a terminal and your router should be what ever is listed as gateway).  And then it will restart the network interface

This is for most linux setups.

Steps you can follow here: https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/changing-dns-settings-on-linux

or this is more specifically for Raspberry pi: http://www.skanc.com/?p=245